# Attaching an object method to an event while retaining the element reference

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dom-events

```
function MyObject() {
  this.name = "";
  this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
}

MyObject.prototype.attachEventHandlers = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
    this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', this.myEventHandler);
  }
};

MyObject.prototype.myEventHandler = function() {
  // Here "this" referst to the element that the event invoked on:
  console.log(this.innerHTML);

  // Is there a way to get the name property like:
  // console.log(this.name);
  // without passing the instance as an argument?
};

var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.name = "Foo";
myObject.attachEventHandlers();
```

I would like to use the `myEventHandler` method as an even handler, but as you know in event handlers `this` refers to the element that that the event was invoked on.

I would like to **both keep a reference to the element that the event was invoked on, and also keep a reference to the object instance**.

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Passing the object instance as an argument to the event handler, like:

   ```
   // ...
       var that = this;
       this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
         that.myEventHandler(that);
       }
   // ...

   MyObject.prototype.myEventHandler = function(that) { // ...
   ```
2. The same as above, but instead of using the prototype method, using an inline function.

I'd rather not use an inline function, as it clutters the code. And I'd rather not pass the object instance as an argument, if I don't have to.

Is there a more idiomatic and simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: `this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){e.target.myEventHandler(e)});`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know about the `Event.target` property. Thanks to @AlexandreThebaldi for pointing it out.

```
// ...
    this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', this.myEventHandler.bind(this));
// ...

MyObject.prototype.myEventHandler = function(e) {
  var el = e.target;

  console.log(el) // Outputs the element.
  console.log(this); // Outputs the object instance.
};
```

This way, I don't need to explicitly pass an argument to the event handler function, and I don't need to use an inline function.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `bind` method on callback function:

```
MyObject.prototype.attachEventHandlers = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
    this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      this.myEventHandler(event.target);
    }.bind(this));
  }
};

/*
 * @param {HTMLElement} element The element that has been clicked.
 */
MyObject.prototype.myEventHandler = function(element) {
  // ...
  console.log(this); // MyOject
};
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks, I knew about `bind`, but didn't know about `Event.target`. I'd rather not explicitly pass an argument to the event handler, so I added my own answer using the `Event.target`. Thanks for pointing it out! I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect answer, I didn't read the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best solution is to use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', this.myEventHandler.bind(this.elements[i], this));
```

Then in the event handler, `this` will refer to the element that the event was invoked on, and the first argument will refer to the class instance.

```
MyObject.prototype.myEventHandler = function(instance) {
  console.log(this) // DOM element
  console.log(instance) // class instance
};
```